# terminal returns node.js web-scraped links out of order

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, terminal

So the code below is meant to go to the links (link1, link2, etc) and output a list of sub-links scraped from the webpages.
The issue is - I am getting the sub-links out of order when I run this through terminal. Eg, I will get a list of sub-links scraped from link3, then link2, then link4, then link1.
Is there a way to correct this so that I obtain the links in the order that I write them in?

```
const urls = [
"link1",
"link2",
"link3",
"link4"]

   for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    const url = urls[i];

 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 const fs = require("fs/promises");

    (async function main() {
      try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' });
        const [page] = await browser.pages();

        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
        
        const data = await page.$$eval("img", (imgs) => {
          return imgs.map(x => x.src) 
        })

        console.log(data);
        fs.writeFile("data.txt", data)

        await browser.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    })();


}
```

Comment: You are calling 4 async functions in parallel Of cause they will be out of order. Use `await`

Comment: where would I use await?